# I recently installed codeblocks (Code :: Blocks IDE) but do not compile the simple test program

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Summarizing the problem as generally as possible:

I used to compile the program via terminal with the sequence of commands even in bash.
Basically:

```
g++ test.cpp -o teste.exe
chmod +x teste.exe
./teste.exe
```

At the terminal it works perfectly. But Codeblock practically does not create the program's executable.
Simple example program created:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I press "Build and run" (At first it detects g++ so I selected the only one I had.).
Nothing, just this:

```
-------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

g++   -c "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.cpp" -o "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.o"
g++  -o "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste" "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.o"   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 
Checking for existence: /home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste

-------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

g++   -c "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.cpp" -o "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.o"
g++  -o "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste" "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.o"   
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

There is some detail that I missed to be able to use the codeblock, otherwise I will be in the terminal and bash. I heard that new students are afraid of the terminal. So I'm trying to use something that should be "easy" (the terminal is easy for me but not for others).

Detail:
Use linux minimal ubuntu version with essential installation.

Comment: What proof can you show that supports the assertion that Codeblocks "does not create the program's executable"? What is your proof that `teste` does not get created in the referenced directory?

Comment: Will a video on youtube work?
from "start" (installation) to "end" (compilation error).

Comment: You don't need a video to post the output of the `ls` command that documents the missing executable file. Simply [edit] your question, highlight your terminal window, and copy/paste the plain text (and add formatting markers in Stackoverflow's editor window to designate the pasted block as unformatted, raw text. Be sure to look at the preview to make sure it's formatted correctly.

Comment: Out put `ls`:
opencv  teste.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything correct except the folder with space, after changing the directory to test the program it worked without problems, with my research I found that this bug exists since 2007 after 13 years, I was surprised to come across this problem not fixed.
Link:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,5003.0.html

No problems:

```
g++ "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.cpp" -o "/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.exe"
```

Same problem:

```
g++ /home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.cpp -o /home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.exe
```

Out put erro:

```
g++: error: /home/williambronzo/Área: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
g++: error: de: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
g++: error: Trabalho/teste.cpp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
g++: error: de: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
g++: error: Trabalho/teste.exe: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

The incredible thing that puts double quotes in the code output (build log), but apparently runs the program underneath without double quotes.

If it weren't for the sam varshavchik tip, I wouldn't have found the problem. After all, I was wondering where the program was putting the, "teste.o" and "teste". Then I looked at the folder spaces. (Noobs error.)

My solution:
Avoid folders with spaces.

Change the:

```
"/home/williambronzo/Área de Trabalho/teste.cpp"
```

For:

```
"/home/williambronzo/Documentos/[Filename without space]/teste.cpp"
```

Probably if your main language or the selected computer language does not include spaces in the directories you will not find an error, but if there is space in any directory you will find this Codeblocks error.

I'm sorry for bothering you with a trivial error and Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the compiler is configured correctly? A similar problem happened to me.
To resolve, go to Settings >> Global Compiler Settings >> Toolchain executables and click on "Auto-Detect".
After that the problem must be solved, if not, make sure that the mingw has been installed correctly.

Comment: The configuration is correct, I am checking other settings.

Comment: About mingw, I am using linux.